# Magento2 Shipping City For Shipping Amount Caluculations

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

I need to apply table rate shipping based on following conditions

> City to City
>
> Metro to City
>
> Metro to Metro
>
> City to Other
>
> City to Special Locations

I written my own module but i am getting only the postal code and country id in $request

```
Array ( [shipping_details] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [seller_id] => 0 [items_weight] => 4.05 [product_name] => My Tshirt) [item_id] => 812 ) ) [dest_country_id] => IN [dest_postal] => 500049 )
```

My code which is caluculating carrier amount as follows. How can i get the city name and state/region id in $request.

```
namespace My\TableRateShipping\Model;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use My\TableRateShipping\Model\ShippingmethodFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\OptionFactory;
use My\TableRateShipping\Model\TableRateShippingFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\Unserialize\Unserialize;

class Carrier extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * Code of the carrier.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const CODE = 'mytablerateshipping';
    /**
     * Code of the carrier.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = self::CODE;
    /**
     * Rate request data.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest|null
     */
    protected $_request;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $_productFactory;
    /**
     * Rate result data.
     *
     * @var Result|null
     */
    protected $_result;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_errors = [];

    protected $_isFixed = true;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;
    /**
     * Raw rate request data.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject|null
     */
    protected $_rawRequest = null;
    /**
     * @var My\TableRateShipping\Model\ShippingmethodFactory
     */
    protected $_mpshippingMethod;
    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager
     */
    protected $_coreSession;
    /**
     * @var OptionFactory
     */
    protected $_itemOptionModel;
    /**
     * @var My\Marketplace\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_mpProductFactory;
    /**
     * @var TableRateShippingFactory
     */
    protected $_mpShippingModel;
    /**
     * @var Unserialize
     */
    protected $_unserialize;
     /**
     * @var Unserialize
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface          $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory  $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface                                    $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory                  $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param ProductFactory                                              $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface                   $objectManager
     * @param ShippingmethodFactory                                     $shippingmethodFactory
     * @param SessionManager                                              $coreSession
     * @param OptionFactory                                               $itemOptionModel
     * @param TableRateShippingFactory                                           $mpshippingModel
     * @param array                                                       $data
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        ShippingmethodFactory $shippingmethodFactory,
        SessionManager $coreSession,
        OptionFactory $itemOptionModel,
        ShippingFactory $mpshippingModel,
        Unserialize $unserialize,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->_mpshippingMethod = $shippingmethodFactory;
        $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
        $this->_itemOptionModel = $itemOptionModel;
        $this->_mpShippingModel = $mpshippingModel;
        $this->_unserialize = $unserialize;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Collect and get rates.
     *
     * @param RateRequest $request
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error|bool|Result
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        $this->setRequest($request);
        $shippingpricedetail = $this->getShippingPricedetail($this->_rawRequest);

        return $shippingpricedetail;
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject|null $request
     * @return $this
     * @api
     */
    public function setRawRequest($request)
    {
        $this->_rawRequest = $request;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Prepare and set request to this instance.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function setRequest(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request)
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $requestData = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $product = $this->_productFactory->create();
        $mpassignproductId = 0;
        $shippingdetail = [];
        $partner = 0;
        $handling = 0;
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $proid = $item->getProductId();
            $options = $item->getProductOptions();
            $mpassignproductId = 0;
            $itemOption = $this->_itemOptionModel->create()
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('item_id', ['eq' => $item->getId()])
                ->addFieldToFilter('code', ['eq' => 'info_buyRequest']);

            if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }

            $weight = $this->calculateWeightForProduct($item);
            if (empty($shippingdetail)) {
                array_push(
                    $shippingdetail,
                    [
                        'seller_id' => $partner,
                        'items_weight' => $weight,
                        'product_name' => $item->getName(),
                        'item_id' => $item->getId(),
                    ]
                );
            } else {
                $shipinfoflag = true;
                $index = 0;
                foreach ($shippingdetail as $itemship) {
                    if ($itemship['seller_id'] == $partner) {
                        $itemship['items_weight'] = $itemship['items_weight'] + $weight;
                        $itemship['product_name'] = $itemship['product_name'].','.$item->getName();
                        $itemship['item_id'] = $itemship['item_id'].','.$item->getId();
                        $shippingdetail[$index] = $itemship;
                        $shipinfoflag = false;
                    }
                    ++$index;
                }
                if ($shipinfoflag == true) {
                    array_push(
                        $shippingdetail,
                        [
                            'seller_id' => $partner,
                            'items_weight' => $weight,
                            'product_name' => $item->getName(),
                            'item_id' => $item->getId(),
                        ]
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        //$request->getDestCity();
        //$request->getDestRegionId();
        //$request->getDestPostcode();

        //$request->getSourceCity();



        if ($request->getShippingDetails()) {
            $shippingdetail = $request->getShippingDetails();
        }
        $requestData->setShippingDetails($shippingdetail);

        $requestData->setDestCountryId($request->getDestCountryId());

        if ($request->getDestPostcode()) {
            $requestData->setDestPostal(str_replace('-', '', $request->getDestPostcode()));
        }


        $this->setRawRequest($requestData);

        return $this;
    }
```

Calling my own function like this

```
if ($shipping->getSize() != 0) {
                $priceArr = $this->getDpriceArrForRate($shipping,$request);
            } else {
                $msg = $this->getErrorMsg($msg, $shipdetail);
            }
```

My getDpriceArrForRate function is like below

```
 public function getDpriceArrForRate($shipping,$request)
    {
         //$request->getDestCity();
        //$request->getDestRegionId();
        //$request->getDestPostcode();

        //$request->getSourceCity();


            print_r($request->getDestCity());
             exit;
       }
```

Its giving empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I changed my code in my modal as follows.

```
         $requestData->setDestCountryId($request->getDestCountryId());
         $requestData->setDestCity($request->getDestCity());
         $requestData->setDestRegionId($request->getDestRegionId());
          $this->setRawRequest($requestData);
```

Now i can access the City , Region and CountryId by calling Raw Request As follows.

```
    $dest_city=$this->_rawRequest->getDestCity();
    $dest_regionid=$this->_rawRequest->getDestRegionId();
    $dest_postcode=$this->_rawRequest->getDestPostcode();
```

Comment: I Want to add buffer weight of currently selected shipping method. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get request city  name from `$request`

For city use `$request->getDestCity()`

For getting region Id use `$request->getDestRegionId()`

For getting region  use `$request->getDestRegion()`

Comment: Its giving empty value.

Comment: I am getting City Name in setRequest function , but i need to use this value in another function. How can i pass this value as global value?

Comment: You have to pass the $request to this function

Comment: I passed $request but not able to get the city name. I shared my code in my question.